# How to get count of distinct field in mongodb java driver

Tags: mongodb, count

I know I can get a distinct list with query like this:

```
db.collections.distinct("fieldName")
```

And get the length of the list with

```
db.collections.distinct("fieldName").length
```

But is there a way to get the `length` in mongodb-java-driver other than in a aggregation query?

Or will implementation such as:

```
 collection.distinct("fieldName", condition).size()
```

is too  inefficiency?

Comment: which `mongo-java-driver` you used?

Comment: @yogesh the official one `mongo-java-driver` version 2.12.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a slight modification of your code:

```
db.collections.distinct("fieldName").length
```

Comment: Sorry, I just find the answer of doing that in a mongodb client shell(while you post the answer, thanks though), but I still don't know how to do than with mongodb-java-driver

Comment: @armnotstrong It would appear that mongodb doesn't support server-side sorting using the distinct command. As such, aggregate query would be your only route.  Performance-wise, it is much better to sort on the client side of things.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I just find **maybe** I can do that with `list.size()` since `distinct` returned a list, but will that be of poor efficiency?

Comment: @armnotstrong Also, perhaps check this out: http://www.journaldev.com/6320/mongodb-distinct-example-using-mongo-shell-and-java-driver